# Identify a 80s spy themed arcade game

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm tying to identify an coin-op arcade game of the 80s. The player controlled some kind of spy, who was chased by other spies across a building. There was at least an elevator, but it wasn't Mission Elevator. Rooms could be entered, that were shown from the top, with walls kind of like Berserk. I remember that unexplored areas were filled with a solid colour. And (less sure about that) items had to be collected. Apart from that, no clues as I never played it myself but often watched a friend play it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1980s arcade game with overhead perspective and line-art cut scenes](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26767/1980s-arcade-game-with-overhead-perspective-and-line-art-cut-scenes)

Comment: @StephenKitt: No that's not it. The graphics were much simpler.

Comment: You mentioned "Mission Elevator", but that wasn't an arcade game, but a home computer game. So you probably mean it wasn't "Elevator Action". You can't enter rooms in that game indeed.

Comment: @scrØllbær - Well, you CAN enter rooms in EA, you just don't see the interiors. And that eliminates Rolling Thunder and Golden Gun as well.

Comment: Sorry, not Golden Gun, Sly Spy.

Comment: Were you in the USA?  England?  Knowing the part of the world/country you were in may help finding the game.

Comment: I was in France at that time. It was an import of course. Perhaps even a bootleg.

Comment: Spy's Demise?  Maybe there was an arcade version?

Comment: @peterferrie: no, but the graphics of that one are nearer to the mark than other suggestions so far.

Answer (score 3):

It's a long shot but could you be thinking of [Spy vs. Spy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_vs._Spy_(1984_video_game)).

Screenshot from C-64 version:

[image: Spy v Spy screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, that's not it. It was a coin-op.

Comment: Such a great game!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if he's talking about the Cloak & Dagger game. I remember it from both the movie and the arcades, it did have a top view similar to Berserk, it did have an elevator you could ride to each level, and you did pick up items in the level. And you played as a spy!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_%26_Dagger_(video_game)

Comment: No, that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm tying to identify an coin-op arcade game of the 80s

Coin-op limits the field, that's useful.

> some kind of spy, who was chased by other spies across a building.

Chasing... and what else? Shooting? Dropping bombs?

> There was at least an elevator, but it wasn't Mission Elevator.

I don't know of a game called Mission Elevator, but I've played my share of [Elevator Action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LM5reigEnv4). Is this what you mean?

> Rooms could be entered, that were shown from the top, with walls kind of like Berserk.

And this is where I lose it... an elevator but also top-down rooms? I don't think I've ever heard of that.

> remember that unexplored areas were filled with a solid colour.

... and back to EA, where the areas were unlit for sections of the building and you could only see the doors and just make out the enemies.

> And (less sure about that) items had to be collected

And EA had that too, in some of the rooms were briefcases you could pick up for bonus points.

To get this one, I think we will need some more details.

Can you be more specific about the "chase" bit? Was the entire game top-down, or just when you were in a room? Any other details you can recall about the graphics or gameplay?

You mention the graphics being simpler than Cloak and Dagger, but those strike me as rather basic indeed. You also mention it being a bit like Berzerk. Would you say the level of complexity of the graphics was very simple, just some lines and sprites? Is there another game you might compare it to in terms of complexity?

Comment: I remember that the building was shown vertically, with the different levels on top of each other. When entering a room, the view was changed to a top view, with a black background and simple line walls like Berserk. Those walls delimited areas that were filled with a solid colour, preventing you from seeing what was inside until you entered the area. But no, it was not Elevator Action.

Comment: Ah, and I think that the CRT was vertical.

Comment: In term of graphical complexity, it was quite basic, yes. That was I cited Bersek as an example. Lines, squares and sprites. But it's very far in my memory now.

Comment: Huh, well you've got me. I suggest posting this, with the expanded bits you've mentioned here, on the Tip-of-my-tounge forum on Reddit. I could do this for you if you like.

Comment: That would be nice, as I don't have a Reddit account myself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one with the title "[005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/005)", hence often overlooked because such numeric titles are easy to miss in lists, by Sega as early as 1981.

> 005 is a 2D arcade game, one of the first games with stealth elements. The main hero is Agent 005 - he must deliver secret attache cases to an awaiting helicopter. He makes his way through various buildings and warehouses, and avoids enemies. Opponents are using flashlights - the player can sneak around in the dark. In other locations the player must escape from opponents - he can throw special objects that immobilize them. After a successful escape, the player gets to the helicopter.

[image: 005 Game starts]

[image: 005 Life lost]

[image: 005 Warehouses]

[image: 005 In helicopter]

Comment: No, that's not it.

Comment: but it was a good shot, wasn't it `:)`